# Calling C function from Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c, macos, ctypes

I'm trying to call C functions from a python script via `ctypes`, but I'm doing something wrong. I wrote a minimal example to show what I'm doing:

## C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

float distance(float ab[]){
 return fabs(ab[0]-ab[1]);
}
```

I save it as `c_library.c` and I compile it with `cc -fPIC -shared -o c_library.so c_library.c`.

## Python code:

```
import ctypes
_c = ctypes.CDLL('c_library.so')
_c.distance.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)]

def distance(ab):
    array_type = ctypes.c_float * 2
    return float(_c.distance(array_type(*ab)))

print(distance(np.array([1.0,3.0])))
```

When I execute it, I get `0.0` as output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't set the restype.

Comment: :facepalm: Thank you.